# ReactNative AsyncGenerator

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use an ES6 `AsyncGenerator` function to retrieve data in my ReactNative app from a paging API, but having no luck. I am reusing code that I've been able to successfully use in a web application also using ES6 and React. I am fairly sure this is going to come down to a configuration issue of some sort, or language support, but I can't figure out what my problem is as the errors aren't particularly helpful. If I must, I can obviously avoid the `AsyncGenerator` and implement this another way.

The basic generator function has this structure:

```
export async function* apiPager() {
  let nextToken = null;
  do {
    const resp = await makeAPICall(nextToken);
    nextToken = resp.nextToken;
    yield resp;
  } while(nextToken)
}
```

The code I use to process the generator is as follows:

```
const pager = apiPager(...)
console.log('pager', pager);
for await (const resp of pager) {
  doThings(resp);
}
```

When I try to use this code, I see the following in the console:

```
pager AsyncIterator {_invoke: ƒ}_invoke: ƒ enqueue(method, arg)arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 2name: "enqueue"prototype: {constructor: ƒ}__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: runtime.js:167[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]__proto__: next: ƒ (arg)return: ƒ (arg)throw: ƒ (arg)Symbol(Symbol.asyncIterator): ƒ ()constructor: ƒ AsyncIterator(generator)__proto__: Object

YellowBox.js:71 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: _iterator[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function
TypeError: _iterator[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function
    at WorkoutHistory.fetchSets$ (blob:http://localhost:8081/8ee39d52-49af-4c3e-a8a7-b3d585ce1223:163566:234)
    at tryCatch (blob:http://localhost:8081/8ee39d52-49af-4c3e-a8a7-b3d585ce1223:23518:19)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (blob:http://localhost:8081/8ee39d52-49af-4c3e-a8a7-b3d585ce1223:23693:24)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (blob:http://localhost:8081/8ee39d52-49af-4c3e-a8a7-b3d585ce1223:23561:23)
    at tryCatch (blob:http://localhost:8081/8ee39d52-49af-4c3e-a8a7-b3d585ce1223:23518:19)
    at invoke (blob:http://localhost:8081/8ee39d52-49af-4c3e-a8a7-b3d585ce1223:23594:22)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/8ee39d52-49af-4c3e-a8a7-b3d585ce1223:23624:13
    at tryCallTwo (blob:http://localhost:8081/8ee39d52-49af-4c3e-a8a7-b3d585ce1223:24829:7)
    at doResolve (blob:http://localhost:8081/8ee39d52-49af-4c3e-a8a7-b3d585ce1223:24993:15)
    at new Promise (blob:http://localhost:8081/8ee39d52-49af-4c3e-a8a7-b3d585ce1223:24852:5)
[![error messages][1]][1]
```

First problem seems pretty obvious, which is that the type of `pager` is `AsyncIterator` and not `AsyncGenerator` as I would see with this same code in my web application. But as far as I understand, either one should be operable with the `for await (...)` loop no? Something funky is happening... enlighten me if you can.

Comment: I'm struggling with this problem too. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Welp... I never did get an answer. I also posted this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27432 and got no traction.

I did find a workaround I will repost here, which is only slightly unsatisfactory:

## Workaround (from github issue)

```js
async function* asyncGen() {
  yield 'whatever';
}

const gen = asyncGen();
while (!gen.done)
  console.log('result', (await gen.next()).value);
```

I suppose this is only slightly annoying, because the syntactic improvement of the `for await (... of ...)` is a bit less valuable than the ability to write a generator function rather than creating an iterator. However, it would be nice to understand what the problem is here.